# Conditional Statement with Operators in Python Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column that has a range of positive and negative integers ('updated_time') and if the integer is negative I would like to add 24 to it but am having some issues. I've tried the following with no success

```
block_subset['updated_time'] = block_subset['updated_time'].apply(lambda x : (x + 24) if x > 
0 else x)
```

Any help would be so much appreciated!

Comment: try: `block_subset['updated_time'] = block_subset['updated_time'].mask( block_subset['updated_time'] > 0),  block_subset['updated_time']  + 24)` OR `block_subset['updated_time'] = block_subset['updated_time'].where( block_subset['updated_time'] <= 0),  block_subset['updated_time']  + 24)`

Comment: Should your `>` be a `<`

Comment: You can also use `np.where` or `.loc` to achieve this. `mask`, `where`, `loc`, and `np.where` are all very similar for these types of operations.

Comment: @DavidErickson Thank you so much for the quick reply! I tried both of those and am getting the following error: Length of values does not match length of index

Comment: @code_newbie please include a minimum reproducible example. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score -1):

It is a lot more readable if you define a temporary variable:

```
t = block_subset['updated_time']
block_subset['updated_time'] = t.mask(t > 0, t + 24)
```

This reads "if t > 0, replace with t + 24"